# Custom post type loop error: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: wp-query, loop

A plugin I am using creates a custom post type for articles ie. 'ht_kb'.

In my themes front page I have a custom loop displaying recent posts of the standard 'post' type. On the same front page I have another custom loop displaying recent posts of the plugins custom 'ht_kb' post type. The standard post type loop works as expected, but with the custom post type loop I am getting the error as posted below.

I am having difficulty understanding the reason for this error and would really appreciate if someone could explain what i am doing wrong and what is the correct way of looping through a custom post type.

The loop below works just fine with the standard 'post' type.

```
//The Query
$post_args = array(
'post_type' => array('post'),
'posts_per_page' => 4
);

$post_query = new WP_Query($post_args);

// The Loop
if ($post_query->have_posts()) {

while ($post_query->have_posts()) {

    $post_query->the_post();
    the_title();
    the_category();
    the_date();
    the_author();
    the_excerpt();
}

//reset loop

wp_reset_postdata();

}

?>
```

The custom post type loop below returns the error:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\localhost\mywebsite\wp->includes\template.php on line 679
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\localhost\mywebsite\wp->includes\template.php on line 679

Loop for the custom post type

```
<?php

// The Query
$article_args = array(
'post_type' => array('ht_kb'),
'posts_per_page' => 4
);

$article_query = new WP_Query($article_args);

// The Loop
if ($article_query->have_posts()) {

while ($article_query->have_posts()) {

    $article_query->the_post();
    the_title();
    the_category();
    the_date();
    the_author();
    the_excerpt();
}

//reset loop

wp_reset_postdata();
}
?>
```

note: If I comment out the_excerpt(); function, The loop does not display the error and (sort of) works as intended although other issues such as, the_category() function does not return any value.

Thanking you for your time and help.

Comment: Are you sure `ht_kb` is defined with title, excerpt and all that extra stuff?

Comment: @kero The plugin includes templates, which do include excerpt,category etc. and display correctly in the respective template parts. in my custom loop the_title() and the_author() display correctly, however the_content and the excerpt cause the error to show. excerpt from plugin: $args = array ('supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'author', 'comments', 'post-formats', 'custom-fields', 'revisions')); register_post_type('ht_kb', $args);

Comment: @kero The problem is definitely related to the theme, as the same loop works correctly without error on a different theme. I am new to WordPress and php, but I will try my best to search for a solution and post back later with results.

Answer (score 0):

Hey this may be a little too late however I had this same issue on my custom made theme.

Firstly it turned out I didn't create any custom posts and secondly, with the loop, because there were no posts I didn't have the content-none file in my theme.

Once this was added the get_template_part( 'content-parts/content', 'none' ); code the error was gone.

Hope this helps someone else :)